# How to resolve : pgAdmin Fatal Error. pgAdmin4.py missing?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have pgAdmin v6.21 installed on my Windows10. It was running for few months and I suddenly got this fatal error while opening the pgAdmin.

***pgAdmin4.py : No such file or directory.***

[image]

I see some suggested reinstall but I have few imp severs and databases configured in it and dont want to lose it or redo that.
Is there any way to resolve it without reinstall?
And if I am reinstalling then how can I get all those databases back?

Answer (score 0):

You need to backup your database(s) first to avoid loosing your data. Try to work around your already installed version of pgAdmin by ensuring the file is there(you might have accidently deleted the file). If this fails, you will need to reinstall pgAdmin but it will be better because you will have your already backed up your data and configurations.
You can backup your data by running the following command in your psql terminal:

```
pg_dump dbname > dumpfile.sql
```

The dumpfile when run will create the databse in the same state at time of backing up your data.
To backup your configurations, assuming your configurations are in the .config files, you can copy the configurations to a different locations, like this:

```
cp /path/to/your/postgresql.conf /path/to/backup/directory
```

Comment: Hi. I went into the folder programFiles\pgAdmin\v6 and that folder is empty no files. Dont know how anything here is missing but surely not my action. Looks like reinstalling is the only option.  But how to back up my configurations? it not even opening.

Comment: You have some customized configurations say like in Postgresql configuration file (postgresql.conf)?

Comment: If your configurations are in the conf files, refer again in the answer above.

Comment: Weird issue. but after few days when I opened again there was no error. it resolved on its own. dont know how. lol Thanks for suggestion.